# The device is not ready. (New-PSSession)

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-remoting

I am creating new powershell session for the remote server. I am getting a very generic error "The device is not ready".
Here is the code:

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName <remoteServerName>
New-PSSession : <remoteServerName> Processing data from remote server <remoteServerName> failed with the following error message: The device is not ready. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSSession -ComputerName <remoteServerName>
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncorrectProtocolVersion,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

at this point, it will create a remote powershell session with target server but it throws an error with The device is not ready. I am using powershell 4.0 version.

I am new to the powershell, so I am not much aware of it. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Windows is the remote server? If the remote server is running PowerShell 2.0, you might have to either upgrade (install WMF 5.1 on both machines), or at enable PowerShell 2.0 Engine feature on the client

Comment: I have Windows version 2012R2 Datacenter UR5 and both remote and client server machine have same powershell version 4.0